# Apk lacks the attribute "platformBuildVersionName" when it's built with Gradle plugin 3.0.1 for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, airwatch

Since I moved from Gradle's plugin for Android Studio from version 2.3.1 to 3.0.1, I'm having problems for deploying a new version of my app into **VMWare Airwatch** environment. Every time I try it, I get the following warning message:

[image]

The warning says:

> The version code of the application is being added is 1090012, which is lower or equal to the former application's version existing in the organizative group. Ask your programmer to actualize the version code to be greater than 1090012.

The thing is that the `apk` file compiled with gradle 2.3.1 differ from building with gradle 3.0.1 in just one tag.

[image]

As can be seeing, the only difference is the paramameter `platformBuildVersionName`, which seems to be enough to cause problems with the instalation of the new vesion in **VMWare Airwatch**.

I've tried adding this to my `build.gradle` file:

```
       applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                setPlatformBuildVersionNameOverride('7.1.1')
            }
        }
```

but the method `setPlatformBuildVersionNaveOverride` does not exist. Is this a normal behaviour for Gradle? How can I fix the lack of this parameter in the apk file?

Comment: Did you tried to remove `buildVersionName` from your gradle once it added automatically ?

Comment: Of course I did. In fact, I added it just to try override the default addition, but, as I said, that method does not exist.

Comment: Since Gradle plugin 3.0.0, a new version of aapt is available  which causes this lack. So the workaround is to disable appt2 from your gradle propeties file ('android.enableAapt2 = false). You should know that the option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.